# How to pass a Form input as a variable to my class method

Tags: python, django

Short question : how can I pass the user's input from a form, to the parameter of my method class ?

The user type a number, and this number is used in the method to multiply another value from the Class fields.

I tried dozen of things, but cant figured out what I am doing wrong
If I update the method to use a constant instead of a variable, everthing is rendering as I want on the template

I keep running into missing positional arguments error.

Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sku

    def multi(self, n = 2):      #setting up a default of 2 initiate
        np = self.price * n      #the method and show self.multi in template
        return np
```

Views

```
def index(request):
    list = Product.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Input(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            value = request.POST.get('data')
            value = form.cleaned_data.get('data')
            x = Product.multi()           # code broken, it does not 
            x(value)                      # initialize the method

    else:
        form = Input(request.POST or None)
```

Form

```
class Input(forms.Form):
    data = forms.DecimalField()
```

template : something around

```
        {% for item in list %}
        <div>
     {{ item.sku }} {{ item.price }} {{ item.multi }} </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You've called the method but you haven't done anything with the result. What did you want to do with it?

Comment: Plus, you're calling it on a new empty Product instance, so there is no value for price to multiply by the input value. What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've added my template to the example. I just want to display the newly calculated value item.multi. As I said it's working if the method calculates self.price * 10 for example). How can I use the form inout to calculate a new input What I am doing wrong ??

Comment: @Gil Inside your if form.is_valid() block, you need to get the saved form data, i.e. value = form.cleaned_data.get('data'), your template also won't work if you just call .multi as it take a parameter and you can't send a parameter through the template.  You could set a temp variable on the product instance e.g. x.data = x.multi(value) but make sure the multi method returns something

Comment: @Omar thank you, I have updated my code with form.cleaned_data.get('data') to save the content of the form
But still, I m lost on how to inject my parameter 'n' (value in the View) in my multi method,
My multi method returns something : that is self.price * 'numerical value, when I remove the extra argument n and use a constant like         np = self.price * 10
It makes the calculation and show this new value in the template

Comment: @Gil The way I would do it is if need be create a custom template filter that takes the product object as a parameter and the parameter for the multi function as the second parameter so you could do something like this in the filter {{ item|multi:10 }}
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to achieve can be done via template tags and filters.
Since by default you can't send parameters into a method of a class instance via the Django template system you need to get creative with template tags.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

I would do the below:

```
# tags.py
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def multi(product, multiple):
    return product.multi(multiple)
```

In your view

```
def index(request):
    list = Product.objects.all()
    value = 2  # some default you want
    form = Input(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            value = form.cleaned_data.get('data')
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'value': value, 'form': form, 'list': list})
```

In your template

```
{% load tags %}
{% for item in list %}
    <div>{{ item.sku }} {{ item.price }} {{ item|multi:value }} </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Where `value` is the value entered on the form which you can feed into the context of the template page rendered

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, with the help of custom filters, I manage to do it. However I'm afraid that with more and more calculation on my objects field, using template tags will become very difficult...

I cant believe there is no way to use a simple method/function to recalculate the new value in my example...

Comment: @Gil yeah I hear you, there is another way to get a similar result without filters, which is to annotate the query set and on the template just use the annotated field from the item rather than using a filter/tag

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet